# How do I return an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am trying to return an IEnumerable. Here is my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAnswersIDs(int id)
{
    using (var context = new MvcApplication4.Entity.test2Entities1())
    {
        return (from p in context.post
                  where p.post_parentid == id && p.post_isdeleted == false
                  select new
                  {
                      p.post_id
                  }).ToList();
    }           
}
```

Is it possible to return an IEnumerable object?

Comment: The List<int> is an IEnumerable<int>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to use any To[Anything] method or something like that. Your mistake is your select way. The correct code is this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAnswersIDs(int id)
{
    using (var context = new MvcApplication4.Entity.test2Entities1())
    {
        return (from p in context.post
                  where p.post_parentid == id && p.post_isdeleted == false
                  select p.post_id);
    }           
}
```

As you see you created an anonymous class which you dont need because you want just an int value.

-- EDIT --

You will be faced to an ObjectDisposed Exception. Becase when you use the returned IEnumerable object it need to use the context which disposed in the GetAnswersIDs method.

So you could return a List instead of IEnumerable or you should define the context out of your GetAnswersIDs method.

This is the code with List

```
public static List<int> GetAnswersIDs(int id)
{
    using (var context = new MvcApplication4.Entity.test2Entities1())
    {
        return (from p in context.post
                  where p.post_parentid == id && p.post_isdeleted == false
                  select p.post_id).ToList();
    }           
}
```

Comment: this will throw an exception once you try to enumerate the returned IEnumerable

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `ToArray` or `ToList` (both `Array<T>` and `List<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>`), since when you return, the context is disposed, I am nearly sure you will get an exception if you use `AsEnumerable` leaving the enumeration itself for later steps:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAnswersIDs(int id)
{
    using (var context = new MvcApplication4.Entity.test2Entities1())
    {
        return (from p in context.post
                  where p.post_parentid == id && p.post_isdeleted == false
                  select p.post_id).ToArray();
    }           
}
```

BTW, I think in your case using linq is more verbose than the non-linq version:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAnswersIDs(int id)
{
    using (var context = new MvcApplication4.Entity.test2Entities1())
    {
        return context.post.
          Where(p => p.post_parentid == id && !p.post_isdeleted).
          Select(p => p.post_id).
          ToArray();
    }           
}
```

As a side note, you might want to consider reformatting the field names in your model to meet the [naming convensions in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx).

Comment: why is  ToArray better than ToList? Or have you chosen ToArray arbitrarily?

Comment: @Matt, You're actually right, but the reason I chose `ToArray` better is because a list is less 'readonly' then an `Array`. and even we know that the list doesn't affect the original collection, it may lead to confusion. because eitherway we're never planning to change or touch the original (from the context) list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx):

However after looking at your code you have to fully materialize the results from the query so using `ToList()` is appropriate - otherwise you will get an exception when you later try to enumerate the results, since it will try to access the DB on a disposed DB context.

Comment: Or even better, use yield return (...)

Comment: @Adi why is that better? It's completely useless here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need a `select new {}`
`select p.post_id` should be sufficient! Then you can surround it with an `.AsEnumerable()`

Answer (score 0):

For the base IEnumerable return, [yield return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) is used

Comment: `yield return` is completely useless for the OP's problem. And obviously `yield return` returns a class that implements `IEnumerable<T>` cast to that interface. Just like the original code returns a `List<T>` cast to that interface. The main difference is that the list is eager, and `yield return` lazy. But the OP needs eager evaluation since he disposes the context.

Comment: We do not know obviously that he needs to use Using statement, do we? Maybe usage of Using is problem and it should be removed. I just made remark that yield return is basically used for returning IEnumerable

Comment: Even without the `using` statement `yield` isn't the right choice here. There are many ways to return an `IEnumerable<T>`.